# internal error while trying to move an instance across zones

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to move instance across zones in same region.

I'm using following command:

```
gcloud compute instances move <instance_name> --zone europe-west1-c --destination-zone europe-west1-b --verbosity=debug
```

And got following output:

```
DEBUG: (gcloud.compute.instances.move) Code: '-1778529648506316197'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 787, in Execute
    resources = args.calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 754, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/compute/instances/move.py", line 88, in Run
    'Moving gce instance {0}'.format(target_instance.Name()))
  File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 266, in WaitFor
    sleep_ms=sleep_ms)
  File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 222, in RetryOnResult
    if not should_retry(result, state):
  File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 260, in _IsNotDone
    return not poller.IsDone(operation)
  File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/operations/poller.py", line 54, in IsDone
    raise OperationErrors(operation.error.errors)
OperationErrors: Code: '-1778529648506316197'
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.move) Code: '-1778529648506316197'
```

I looked into Operations in google compute UI, and moveInstance status is INTERNAL_ERROR.

No instances were moved, but it did create temporary IP address which I had to manually delete.

I can't find any details for this issue.

I have tried updating my gcloud components, and ensured that our project meets required quotas for move operation.

How do I solve this ?

**edit:**
I have tried to manually set --no-auto-delete on the node's root persistent disk. Then I ran the 'move' command again and my instance disappeared. I have all of the disks and snapshots so I can recreate my instance. I will run the migration manually for this node -- which does not explain what gone wrong.

Comment: I tried to replicate this on my end and was able to move without any problem. Make sure [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#requirements) are fulfilled and instance is not in shutdown state before moving the instance. Also, as work around you can take [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of the current instance disk in "europe-west1-c" and [create a new instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot) in europe-west1-b using the snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is how I solved my problem. I have manually recreated my instances (and persistent disks) on target zone. I have not tried the 'move' command since.

Comment: @JamImrich Thanks for sharing. Let me know if you test the 'gcloud compute instances move' command and still have issues considering  [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#requirements) are fulfilled and instance is not in shutdown state before moving the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Comment as an answer,

Make sure [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#requirements) are fulfilled and instance is not in shutdown state before moving the instance. Also, as work around take the [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of the current instance disk in "europe-west1-c" and [create a new instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot) in europe-west1-b using the snapshot.

For reference, check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/move).